# How do reaction mechanisms go from proposed to approved?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Pretty much what it says in the title, I've just been wondering lately, what makes a mechanism be recognized by the scientific community as the most likely thing that happens on the molecular/atomic level when the corresponding chemical reaction takes place in real life?